# TextInput focuses on scroll in React Native

Tags: react-native

In regular native behavior, scrolling an unfocused text view does not make it focus. In React Native however, when you have a multiline TextInput, and you try to scroll, it immediately focuses.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInput.js#L731), this seems to be by design, as the text view is wrapped in a `TouchableWithoutFeedback` that [calls focus on press](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInput.js#L811).

Any workarounds short of forking React Native?

Comment: Did you ever find a work around for this? I'm struggling with the same issue.